# visual studio 2017 search tfs changeset comment

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, comments, changeset

I would like to search for tfs changeset comment in visual studio 2017.
Any way or tools except "View history and copy all to excel and search"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below PowerShell script, just replace the search text `07` as your own
behind `like '*07*'`

```
$baseUrl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?maxCommentLength=30&api-version=1.0"         
$changesets = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential).value|where({$_.comment -like '*07*'})

$changesetResults = @()

foreach($changeset in $changesets){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "changesetId" = $changeset.changesetId
          "author" = $changeset.author.uniqueName
          "checkedInBy" = $changeset.checkedInBy.uniqueName
          "createdDate" = $changeset.createdDate
          "comment" = $changeset.comment
        } 

    $changesetResults += $customObject      
}

$changesetResults | Select `
                changesetId, 
                author, 
                checkedInBy,
                createdDate,
                comment #|export-csv -Path C:\Changesets.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

---

If you are using VS client, you can also use below extensions to search with comments:

- [Find Changeset By Comment 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1278813.FindChangesetByComment2015)
- [TFS History Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jvasani.TFSHistorySearch)

Comment: Nothing says "great source control system" like not having basic search features.

Answer (score 4):

Update for us people still using TFS: use the VS 2017 Extension "Find Changeset By Comment 2017" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheDan.FindChangesetByComment

Then you get this right-click menu item in Source Control Explorer:
[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include a brief description of the extension, how it works, and how it solves the problem? This would help to ensure that your answer will not be deleted. Please see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605